# How can I insert multiple rows into a database using results from another data query and posts from the same page?

Tags: php, sql, multiple-columns

I am trying to gather a random amount of members from my database, get their id numbers and use them to insert multiple entries into another table using the ids and some posted info from the same page.

Current (non-working) code:

```
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Send Mail") {
   $rid = $_SESSION["userid"];
   //is amount of members sending to
   $to = $_POST["credits"];
   $messaging = $_POST["message"];
   $sub = $_POST["subject"];

   ///need all ids for amount of membes sending to    
   $getodds = mysql_query("select Id from `oto_members` ORDER BY RAND() Limit '$to';");

   ...

   ///insert a new line for each member sending to using ids from $getodds query
   @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mp_creditmail` (`Id`, `message`, `subject`, `read`) VALUES ('$values', '$messaging', '$sub', no) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL can insert multiple records in a table with a query. You can look at the following link. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/insert-select.html

Looking at the example could use the following statement to what you need.

```
///insert a new line for each member sending to using ids from $getodds query
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'mp_creditmail' ('Id', 'message', 'subject', 'read') SELECT oto_members.Id, '$messaging', '$sub', 'no' FROM oto_members ORDER BY RAND() Limit '$to';");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer your question, but your code/question is a little unclear. I will assume that you want to use the id's obtained in $getodds in your second query where '$values' is. Also, if you are using php version 5 or newer, you should use a non-deprecated query function like mysqli_query()

```
foreach($getodds as $values) {
    @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mp_creditmail` (`Id`, `message`, `subject`, `read`) 
    VALUES ($values, $messaging, $sub, 'no')" or die(mysql_error());
}
```

mysqli_query() would look like this

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
foreach($getodds as $values) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `mp_creditmail` (`Id`, `message`, `subject`, `read`)
        VALUES ($values, $messaging, $sub, 'no')";
    $result = @mysqli_query($link, $query)
}
```

Hope this helps. If not, try to clarify your question.